# Meteor value of option element outside of event

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a Session value that contains the value of an account that I want to set as the selected value while populating a Select statement. When I try and get the value using this.value I get "Unexpected identifier". How can I look at this outside of an Event Handler?

Templates:

```
<template name="transactions">
 <form id="trx_form">
  <select id="account_selector">
    {{> account_selector}}  
  </select>
  <br>
   To or From: <input type="text" value="" size="52" id="to_from"><br>
   <<input type="submit" value="Save" id="save_trx">
 </form>
</template>

<template name="account_selector">
    {{#each accounts}}
     {{#if selectedAcct}}
        <option value="{{this}}" SELECTED>{{this}}</option>
    {{else}}
        <option value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
     {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Helper Functions:

```
    Template.account_selector.accounts = function() {
        // account_categories is a Global array of pre-defined categories
        var pairings = [];
        for (var b = 0, l = account_categories.length; b < l; b++) {
            var category= account_categories[b];
            var acctName = "";
            var accountCursor = account_categories[b].find();               
            accountCursor.forEach( function(acct) {
                acctName = acct.acct_name;
                if (acctName > "")
                {                       
                        pairings.push(category + ":" + acctName);                       
                }
            });
        }
        return pairings;
    };

    Template.account_selector.selectedAcct ({
            var thisAcct = this.value;
            ... Unexpected identifier ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the handlebars each, the data context (this) is the current data element,not dom element. In your case you have a string in the form category:accountName that you can use to get the name to compare with the session.

Comment: Thanks Mark. In the helper I changed it to `Template.account_selector.selectedAcct = function(acctName) { console.log("Looking at " + acctName); }` and then pass it like `{{#if selectedAcct this}}` and all is well in the World!